# Why the props that are passed to memo are don't store the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-memo

I am trying to optimize my React list rendering using the React memo feature of manual props comparison. I have generated a list of simple "toggle" buttons:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Toggle } from "./Toggle";

export default function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState({ a: true, b: true, c: true });
  const handleClick = x => {
    console.log(list);
    const currentValue = list[x];
    setList({ ...list, [x]: !currentValue });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {Object.keys(list).map(x => (
        <Toggle key={x} isChecked={list[x]} name={x} onChange={handleClick} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the "toggle" button:

```
import React from "react";

const areEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  return prevProps.isChecked === nextProps.isChecked;
};

const ToggleComponent = ({ isChecked, name, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{isChecked ? "This is true" : "This is false"}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => onChange(name)}>{name}</button>
    </>
  );
};

export const Toggle = React.memo(ToggleComponent, areEqual);
```

My issue is that the list object actually doesn't store the expected value. Every time I click on the buttons I get the same, default one `{ a: true, b: true, c: true }` (it is visible in the `console.log` of `handleClick`), but if I delete the `areEqual` function, everything works properly again and the list object is updated as it should be.

[Code Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-water-1t1gd?file=/src/App.js)

[image: Edit cool-sun-wq1f6]

EDIT:

I saw that if I change the whole thing into an array and wrap every button into an object, the memo feature works as intended.

[Code Sandbox example with array](https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-tree-sjzm2?file=/src/App.js)

[image: Edit cool-sun-wq1f6]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the `handleClick` function is created and passed once to a `Toggle` Component.
And `handleClick's` closure contains the old `list` value, so whenever the old value change it doesn't get updated.

The easiest fix is to benefit from the second signature of the state updater: a function that accepts in parameter the old state value.

So whenever it is called, react will pass the old state value to it.

```
const handleClick = x => {
  setList(old => ({ ...old, [x]: !old[x] }));
};
```

You also need to `memoize` the handleClick function, because `it is recreated at each render` of the component holding the state:

```
const handleClick = React.useCallback(x => {
  setList(old => ({ ...old, [x]: !old[x] }));
}, [setList]);
```

Here is working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-currying-o00ct)